# How to write a static C++ library and link it to an executable using g++ on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, static-libraries, static-linking

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "main()" << std::endl;
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  void foo() {
      std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Compile static library:

```sh
$ g++ foo.cpp -static
```

Error:

```sh
undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

But this compiles:

```sh
$ g++ foo.cpp -shared -o foo.lib
```

Now I have a static library named `foo.lib` (supposedly).

I try to compile an executable that links to it:

```sh
$ g++ -L -lfoo main.cpp -o main.exe
```

And get this error:

```sh
'foo' was not declared in this scope
```

But `foo` is declared in the static library that I'm linking with.  If the link works, I don't think I need to declare it in **main.cpp** also.  So why isn't the link working?

---

**Update.**

I added `void foo();` to **main.cpp** so it doesn't complain that `foo` needs to be declared.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo();

int main() {
    std::cout << "main()" << std::endl;
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

So I try to compile again and I get this new error:

```sh
undefined reference to `foo()'
```

Why would I need to define `foo` in **main.cpp**?  It's already defined in **foo.cpp** which is the static library.

If I have to define `foo` in **main.cpp** that defeats the entire purpose of linking to the library **foo.lib**.

**UPDATES**

- Removing all the `extern "C" {` ... `}` lines doesn't make the "`foo` is undefined" errors go away.

Comment: The function must be declared when calling that function. This is how C++ works. The compiler must know the name of the function and the types of all parameters. Linking happens ***after*** compilation. The code must be compiled first.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this, please delete your account.  I wrote a very clear question with minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I declared `foo` at the top of **main.cpp** (see my updated post) but now it complains that `foo` is undefined.  If I have to define `foo` in **main.cpp** that defeats the purpose of linking.

Comment: No, it does not "defeat the purpose of linking". Linking to a library does not eliminate the need to declare functions. That's why all commonly used libraries comes with header files that declare all functions in the library. If the act of linking with the library obviates the need to declare any functions in the library then there wouldn't be any need to have header files, would there? And since in the library, `foo()` is defined with "C" linkage, then the declaration you added to `main.cpp` must have "C" linkage too, right?

Comment: I declared the function as you suggested in your first comment.  Now it's complaining that it isn't defined.  I am okay with declaring it in **main.cpp**.  I am not okay with **defining** it in **main.cpp**; defining `foo` in both **main.cpp** and **foo.cpp** defeats the purpose of the static library **foo.cpp**.

Comment: No, this is not what static libraries are all about. The purpose of a library is not to avoid declaring functions. That's not what static libraries exist for. And I explained the reason for your linking error in my last comment.

Comment: I am making a distinction between declaring and defining that I don't think is being conveyed to you clearly.  `void foo();` is a declaration.  `void foo() { std::count << "bar" << std::endl; }` is a definition.  At least according to my knowledge.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wrapping the declaration `void foo();` in **main.cpp** with `extern "C" { ... }` does not make the error go away.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got the impression that I suggested defining `foo()` in `main.cpp`. I reread all of my comments. I have not made any such suggestion, and I explained the reason for the linking error, and the error in your declaration.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I reread all the comments again and am having trouble understanding where you explained the reason for the error.  Something about `C` linkage?  I tried wrapping both declarations of `foo` in both files with `extern "C" {...}` (presumably to avoid the name `foo` getting mangled differently in both files) and that didn't make the error go away.  Are you suggesting I remove all the `extern "C" {...}` lines from both files and then it will work?  **EDIT:** I just tried that.  It didn't change the error.  It still says `foo` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows are the magical incantations you seek:

- main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
extern void foo();
int main() { 
  std::cout << "main()" << std::endl; 
  foo();
}
```

- foo.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void foo() { 
  std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; 
}
```

Console commands:

```sh
$ g++ -o foo.obj -c foo.cpp
```

```sh
$ ar rcs foo.lib foo.obj
```

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp foo.lib -o main.exe
```

These spells conjure up the static lib **foo** with the executable **main** statically linked to it.